# Automated Data Import Stored Procedure From an Excel File

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

I have this Excel file:

[image]

Based on this data, I want to create a stored procedure that will identify the correct meter, if it exists, and perform either an insert or update to the monthly data.

Here is the `MonthlyData` table:

[image]

I really have no idea where to get started on this. Sorry about the tables, I am new here and I cannot post pictures yet. Please copy the tables and paste it in Excel.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you peterm for formatting the tables.

Comment: ***WHAT*** database system are you planning to store this into and a write a stored procedure for? SQL is just the query language - but it's used by **many** database systems - MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, DB2 and many more. Which one are **you** using??

Comment: I am planning to use MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably easiest to create an SSIS package for this if you're going to do this repeatedly.

First, create two tables:

1. myDataRaw
2. myDataCleaned

With myDataRaw, you truncate the table and then upload the Excel file into that table using a data upload object.

Create the stored procedure to work with the raw data. I would truncate the myDataCleaned table and then do a `INSERT ... SELECT` to it, making the `WHERE` clause specific to finding the account meters that you're looking for. If there are a lot, you can create another table to hold the specific account meters you want to import and use it in your `WHERE` clause.

I hope that helps get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using MERGE Query? I have no idea what 'meter' in this context mean, but if its something that can be checked in database itself, then MERGE query will be the best solution to your problem.
http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.6/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/merge-statement/